# Where do Kerbal Space Program add-ons have to be placed (with the Steam version)?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I use the Steam version of Kerbal Space Program and I don't know where add-ons have to be installed.

The answer may be easy to find but this question hasn't be asked here yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've downloaded an addon, you have to put the files (unzip them if they come in a <kbd>.zip</kbd> archive file) in the <kbd>GameData</kbd> folder, for example on Windows 64 bits this is this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Kerbal Space Program\GameData
```

If you use another OS see the [official Wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Root_directory#Default_location) to find the root directory of Kerbal Space Program.

Example: I installed the *WaypointManager* add-on in the <kbd>GameData</kbd> directory and the result is a <kbd>C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Kerbal Space Program\GameData\WaypointManager</kbd> dictory containing the add-on files: <kbd>WaypointManager.cfg</kbd>, <kbd>WaypointManager.dll</kbd>, etc.

Source: [Tutorial:Installing Addons (official wiki)](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Tutorial:Installing_Addons#Step_3_-_Placing_the_addon_in_your_game).